# Изменение расположения кнопок настройки и hamburger

Tags: android

Как настроить расположение кнопки настроек и hamburger, так чтобы они были сверху, а не по середине. Ну или подскажите, что загуглить, чтобы найти руководство.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте `minHeight="@android:attr/actionBarHeight"` или как-то так

Comment: Нормально настроить разметку тулбара

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте настроить параметр 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html#attr_Toolbar_buttonGravity